# How do you calculate the key space of an English monoalphabetic cipher where no letters are in the original position?

Tags: cryptography

I've just started learning about cryptography and learned that the keyspace of a monoalphabetic cipher is the result of a permutation 26x25x24...x3x2x1. But that takes into account keys where cipher letters can match the original plaintext letter. If I don't want any letters to represent the original letter, how do I calculate the new keyspace? Maybe I'm naive, but is it as simple as starting the permutation from 25 instead of 26 or is there some other method needed to calculate the total possible keys? I've tried to find the answer on Google and Stackoverflow but I couldn't find it. I apologize if this is a stupid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called a [derangement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement):

> In combinatorial mathematics, a derangement is a permutation of the elements of a set, such that no element appears in its original position. In other words, a derangement is a permutation that has no fixed points.

The operation is written `!n` and is given by the equation `!n=(n-1)(!(n-1)+!(n-2))`, where `!0` is 1 and `!1` is 0.  For example, you could write the following Ruby code to do it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

def derangements(n)
  case n
  when 0
    1
  when 1
    0
  else
    (n - 1) * (derangements(n - 1) + derangements(n - 2))
  end
end

puts derangements(ARGV[0].to_i)
```

Running this code with 26 gives us 148 362 637 348 470 135 821 287 825.  Such a cipher has a little more than 86 bits of entropy, but would quickly fall to letter frequency cryptanalysis.